# Small view of camera

Tags: camera

When I first started using blender when I switched to camera view the rectangle of camera was bigger but now it is very small and it is very difficult to see what camera is seeing.
I have attached a image of current senari

Comment: Try scrolling the mouse wheel to zoom in and out. You can also use the Numpad + and - buttons. Also, I think you forgot to attach the image.

Comment: I realised my mistake actually I forgot to turn off the lock camera to view setting.  But still thanks a lot